# param is missing or the value is empty: answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to ruby on rails and I'm not understanding what exactly I'm doing wrong. I have a form for submitting a question for a multiple choice trivia game the question is supposed to be saved to a question database table and the 4 answers saved to an answer table with the question_id as a foreign key. However whenever I click the submit button with valid data entered for all fields, I keep getting the error, "param is missing or the value is empty: answer" from this block of code in my questions controller:

```
def answer_params
   params.require(:answer).permit({:question_id => [@question.id]},:answer_text, :correct)
end
```

Here is the full class for my questions_controller.rb:

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

def new
  @question = Question.new
  @answer1 = Answer.new
  @answer2 = Answer.new
  @answer3 = Answer.new
  @answer4 = Answer.new
end



def create
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
    if @question.save
      @answer1 = Answer.new(answer_params)
      @answer2 = Answer.new(answer_params)
      @answer3 = Answer.new(answer_params)
      @answer4 = Answer.new(answer_params)
      if @answer1.save && @answer2.save && @answer3.save && @answer4.save 
      redirect_to root_path
    end
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def question_params
    params.require(:question).permit(:username, :question)
  end

  def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit({:question_id => [@question.id]}, :answer_text, :correct)
  end

end
```

answers_controller.rb:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
     def new
        @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)
     end

    def create
        @question = Question.find(params[:id])
        @answer = Answer.new(answer_params)

        if @answer.save
            redirect_to root_path
        end
    end

    private
  def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit({:question_id => [@question.id]}, :answer_text, :correct)
  end
end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(@question) do |f| %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :username, :value => current_user.email %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :category %>
    <%= f.text_field :category %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :question %>
    <%= f.text_field :question %>
    <br>
    <%= f.fields_for(@answer1) do |c| %>
        <%= c.label :correct_answer %>
        <%= c.text_field :answer_text %>
        <%= c.hidden_field :correct, :value => true %>
        <br>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.fields_for(@answer2) do |i| %>
        <%= i.label :incorrect_answer1 %>
        <%= i.text_field :answer_text %>
        <%= i.hidden_field :correct, :value => false %>
        <br>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.fields_for(@answer3) do |j| %>
        <%= j.label :incorrect_answer2 %>
        <%= j.text_field :answer_text %>
        <%= j.hidden_field :correct, :value => false %>
        <br>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.fields_for(@answer4) do |k| %>
        <%= k.label :incorrect_answer3 %>
        <%= k.text_field :answer_text %>
        <%= k.hidden_field :correct, :value => false %>
    <% end %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit my question", class: "btn btn-primary"%>
<% end %>
```

question.rb:

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :answers
end
```

answer.rb:

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Try using `nested_attributes_for` define in your question model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true`

Comment: @Sontya thanks, but that didn't work either.

Comment: that's not the only change, you have to make change in controller `new` method and form too

Comment: your `new` method should look like this `def new
        @question = Question.new
        @question.answers.build
    end`

Comment: you have to create `answers` on question

Comment: Please post the params which you are getting in terminal after clicking save button.